# C# ThreadAbortException, find who is calling the abort

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, thread-abort

I have C# method that is implemented as a stored procedure. The stored procedure is run from SQL Server

The method just launches a separate native process and then loops using `HasExited` & `WaitForExit(500)` methods until the native process has exited out.

In some cases the native process can take a few hours to exit out and when it does, intermittently the C# method receives a ThreadAbortException. Below is the stack

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, UInt32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, Int64 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.WaitForExit(Int32 milliseconds)
   at MYSQLCLRLib.MYAPP.MyMethod(String operation, String executable, String bkParam, String stdin)
```

I have checked my code and there is no call to `Thread.Abort()`. How do I figure who and why the abort is being sent?

Comment: If you're expecting SQL Server to tolerate a thread running code for several *hours* you may definitely be asking too much, given the veritable straitjacket of restrictions SQL Server normally puts on CLR code if you don't mark it unsafe. My uneducated guess would be that this gets called from the engine itself; if so you may see a message to that effect in the error log (`sp_readerrorlog`). Strongly consider rethinking this approach where SQL Server isn't the one starting this workflow, but only a part of it driven by an external script/application.

Comment: You also don't mention who or what is calling the stored procedure. If an external client is doing this, it has to remain connected to SQL Server for the full duration of the procedure's execution, because the execution of the command will be terminated if the connection is closed -- that, too, should be a solid reason not to favor this approach, especially since terminating the connection or the wait *isn't* going to terminate the external process, meaning troubleshooting and recovery is also hard.

Comment: As a further point: aborting a thread is bad at the best of times (it can cause all sorts of unexpected issues), but doing it inside SQL Server is sheer madness. I suggest you use something like a Service Broker queue to check for results.

Comment: How is your code being run? Is it inside a windows service, IIS web site, scheduled task?

Answer (score 0):

If you paste some snippet of your try catch block it will be great .
but in your case thread.Abort() or Abort should be somewhere in try block.SUppose , if your thread inside the try block you still want to abort that thread , cant write abort everywhere so .

`try`
`{`
`.. Aborting thread here`

`}` 
`catch(ThreadAbortException)`
`{`
`throw;`
`}`
`catch(Exception ex)`
`{`
`..Exception code`   
`}`